# robt's Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have implemented a linked list in C++. I would love to get feedback on how I can improve my code. Should I include more comments to my code or does my code have sufficient logical flow? I would also appreciate comments on how I could make my code more concise. I have tried to make sure to stop all memory leaks. Please let me know if there are more that I have not addressed.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

//Node class 
template <class T> 
class Node{
    public:
        T data; 
        Node<T> *next;

        Node(T data, Node<T> *next); 
};

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T data, Node<T> *next){
    this->next = next;
    this->data = data;
}


//LinkedList class
template <class T> 
class  LinkedList{ 
    public:
        //fields
        Node<T> *head;
        int size;

        //methods
        LinkedList();
        void push(T data);
        void append(T data);
        T pop();
        T removeLast();
        void clear();
        int getSize();    
        void printList();

};

/* LinkedList Constructor
   Sets head of the linkedlist to null,
   Sets size to 0 */
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(){
    this->head = NULL;
    this->size = 0;
}

//getSize:returns the size of the list.
template <class T>
int LinkedList<T>::getSize(){
    return this->size;
}


/* push: adds a node to the front of the list, 
   stores the given data in the node,
   increments size of list */
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::push(T data){
    Node<T> *n = new Node<T>(data, this->head);
    this->head = n;
    this->size++;   
}


/* append: adds a node to the end of the list, 
   stores the given data in the node,
   increments size of list */
template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::append(T data){
    Node<T> *n = new Node<T>(data, NULL);
    Node<T> *start = this->head; 

    if (start == NULL){ 
        this->head=n;  
        this->size ++; 
        return; 
    }

    while (start->next != NULL){
        start = start->next; 
    }

    start->next = n; 
    this->size ++; 
}

/* pop: removes the node at the front of the list,
   returns the associated data. */
template <class T>
T LinkedList<T>::pop(){
    Node<T> *h = this->head;

    //if list is empty
    if (h==NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    //if list has only one node
    if (h->next==NULL){ 
        T ret = h->data; 
        this->head = NULL;
        this->size --; 
        return ret; 
    }

    //if list has multiple nodes
    else{
        T ret = this->head->data;
        this -> head = h->next;
        this->size --;
        return ret;
    }

    delete h;

}

/*removes the last node in the list 
  returns the associated data.*/
template <class T>
T LinkedList<T>::removeLast(){
    Node<T> *h = this->head;

    //if list is empty
    if (h==NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    //if list has only one node
    if (h->next==NULL){ 
        return this->pop();
    }

    //if list has multiple nodes
    while (h->next->next != NULL){
        h = h->next; 
    }

    T ret = h->next->data; 
    h->next = NULL;
    this->size--;

    delete h->next;

    return ret; 

}


/*removes all of the nodes from the list, 
freeing the associated data using the given function */
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::clear(){

    //if list is empty
    if (this->size == 0){
        std::cout<<"Cannot Clear Empty List"<<std::endl;
        return;
        }

    Node<T> *h = this->head;
    Node<T> *n = NULL;
    while (h != NULL) {
        n = h->next;
        delete h;
        h=n;
    }

    this->head = NULL;
    this->size = 0;
    std::cout<<"Cleared List"<<std::endl;
}


template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::printList(){
    int i = 1;

    //if list is empty
    if (this->size == 0){
        std::cout<<"Cannot Print Empty List"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }

    Node<T> *n = this->head;

    //if there is only one element
    if (this->size ==1){
        std::cout<<i<<": "<<n->data<<std::endl;
    }

    while(n){
        std::cout<<i<<": "<<n->data<<std::endl;
        n = n->next;
        i++;
    }
    delete n;
}


int main(){ 
    LinkedList<int> list;

    //testing push
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; ++i)
        list.push(i);

    std::cout<<"After Pushing"<<std::endl;
    list.printList(); //testing printList()

    std::cout<<"\nSize of list: "<<list.getSize()<<std::endl;//testing getSize()

    //testing pop
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j){
        int output=list.pop();
        std::cout<<"Popped: "<<output<<std::endl;
    }

    std::cout<<"\nAfter Popping"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Size of list: "<<list.getSize()<<std::endl;
    list.printList();

    //testing Append
    list.append(0);
    list.append(20);

    std::cout<<"\nAfter Append"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Size of list: "<<list.getSize()<<std::endl; //testing getSize() again
    list.printList(); //testing printList() after append

    //testing RemoveLast
    list.removeLast();
    std::cout<<"\nAfter RemoveLast"<<std::endl;
    list.printList();

    std::cout<<std::endl;

    //testing clear
    list.clear(); //output: cleared
    list.clear(); //output: cannot clear empty list

    std::cout<<"\nAfter Clear"<<std::endl;
    list.printList();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is broken. `Node<T> *n` in `push` doesn't allocate a new node, it points somewhere undefined. `return 0` in `pop` doesn't work if `T` isn't an arithmetic type (it could be a struct or a class).

Comment: Have you actually tested this?  It has serious warnings, and crashes when I attempt to run.  That indicates that this code isn't quite ready for review.  Please fix the problems, then you'll be very welcome to post it here!

Comment: ps. Don't use `malloc()` and `free()` in C++ code.

Comment: [What is the difference between new/delete and malloc/free?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240212/14065)

Comment: Hey! I have made changes to my code. It is free of bugs. I apologise for the previous post. I would appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Don't write `this->`

Within member functions `this->data` is redundant. It add visual clutter and does not usually aid in understanding.  So for example, we have the existing `Node` constructor:

```
template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T data, Node<T> *next){
    this->next = next;
    this->data = data;
}
```

I'd write that in a more modern style like this:

```
template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T data, Node<T> *next) :
    data{data},
    next{next}
{ }
```

### Prefer `private` to `public` where practical

The `LinkedList` class has its only data members `head` and `size` as public members.  Rather than do it that way, it would be better to keep it private.  Generally, it's best to keep the internals of a class private to reduce linkage among objects to only what they need.  This simplifies the interface and therefore the maintenance.  In a similar vein, the data members of `Node` could be private and the `LinkedList` class could be declared a friend to keep access but only within that class.  Better still, put the `Node` definition inside the `LinkedList` class -- it's the only context in which a `Node` is used or needed.

### Don't use `std::endl` if you don't really need it

The difference betweeen `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `'\n'` just emits a newline character, while `std::endl` actually flushes the stream.  This can be time-consuming in a program with a lot of I/O and is rarely actually needed.  It's best to *only* use `std::endl` when you have some good reason to flush the stream and it's not very often needed for simple programs such as this one.  Avoiding the habit of using `std::endl` when `'\n'` will do will pay dividends in the future as you write more complex programs with more I/O and where performance needs to be maximized.

### Use only required `#include`s

The code has `#include`s that are not needed.  This clutters the code and makes it more difficult to read and understand.  Only include files that are actually needed.  In this code, these two are not needed:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
```

### Use `nullptr` rather than `NULL`

Modern C++ uses `nullptr` rather than `NULL`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr/1283623#1283623) for why and how it's useful.

### Use whitespace to improve readability

Lines like this:

```
std::cout<<i<<": "<<n->data<<std::endl;
```

become much easier to read with a little bit of whitespace:

```
std::cout << i << ": " << n->data << '\n';
```

Note, too, that as per the advice above, it's now using `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`.

### Simplify the code

The current list printing routine looks like this (after removing all the redundant `this->` stuff):

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::printList(){
    int i = 1;

    //if list is empty
    if (size == 0){
        std::cout<<"Cannot Print Empty List"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }

    Node<T> *n = head;

    //if there is only one element
    if (size ==1){
        std::cout<<i<<": "<<n->data<<std::endl;
    }

    while(n){
        std::cout<<i<<": "<<n->data<<std::endl;
        n = n->next;
        i++;
    }
    delete n;
}
```

There are two problems with this.  First, `delete n;` at the end is an error.  `n` is a pointer and was not created using `new` and so must not be deleted using `delete`.  Second, it's more complex than it needs to be.  An alternative:

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::printList(){
    if (size == 0){
        std::cout << "Cannot Print Empty List\n";
        return;
    }
    Node<T> *n = head;
    for (int i=1; i <= size; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << n->data << '\n';
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

### Separate data manipulation from output

The `clear` function really does two things.  It removes all the nodes from the list and then it prints the result of the operation.  Better would be to separate the two; have the `clear` function only clear the nodes and return a `bool` to indicate `true` if at least one node was cleared or `false` to indicate that the list was initially empty.

### Use const where practical

The current `printList()` routine does not (and should not) modify the underlying object, and so it should be declared `const`:

```
void printList() const;
```

The same is true of `getSize()`.

### Consider keeping a `tail` pointer

This list provides operations on both the head and the tail, but traverses the entire list every time a tail-oriented operation is done.  Simpler would be to keep a `tail` pointer as a private member and avoid traversing the list when it's not needed.

### Fix the bugs

The `pop()` routine does not `delete` the node it removes.  That's a bug that should be fixed because right now it leaks memory.  A more subtle bug is what happens with an empty list:

```
if (h==nullptr){
    return 0;
}
```

This assumes that type `T` may be constructed from `0` which isn't necessarily true.  Better would be `return T{};` which only requires that `T` must be default-constructable.  A rewritten, bug free and simplified version is this:

```
template <class T>
T LinkedList<T>::pop(){
    if (head == nullptr){
        return T{};
    }
    T ret{head->data};
    Node<T> *doomed{head};
    head = doomed->next;
    delete doomed;
    --size;
    return ret;
}
```

There's a similar problem (and fix) in `removeLast()`.

### Think of the user

Instead of always printing to `std::cout`, consider instead passing a `std::ostream&` as a parameter to `printList`.  This would allow the user to redirect the output to any stream.

### Provide a destructor

The `LinkedList` object should clean itself up if it goes out of scope and the way to do that is to provide a destructor.  Once you fix `clear`, you could use it as the basis for the destructor:

```
~LinkedList() { clear(); }
```